# Picture link not updating when new links are added

Tags: bug, status-completed

[Example](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/36233/revisions) (check revision 9 side-by-side markdown):

After a new link is added, image links are shifted:

`[![enter image description here][4]][3]`

As Federico noted, "this happens if the link is added before the picture."

Comment: in particular, I noticed that this happens if the link is added *before* the picture

Comment: Might be better on Meta.SE rather than Aviation Meta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This took a while to figure out - a few different features fighting each other.

The fix has been completed, but is yet to be deployed - it will be in a revision after 2017.3.16.25436.

Thanks for reporting!

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for the quick fix!